# HTML5 video elements loading time

Tags: html, django, apache2

I just want to figure out why my website is serving video files without coherence.

First of all, I have created my website on ODROID-XU4 and OS is Ubuntu. Also, using Django and Apache2 as Framework

Anyway, here is my problem.
Videos won’t start instantly when I click the play button
But, funny thing is some video files with big size do play instantly.

For example, when I upload 3GB of video(mkv) and click play button, it plays instantly.

However, another video file which is only 1.8GB uploaded won’t be played before fully loaded.

Please, I am waiting for answer from someone who had similar experience

Below, I add my HTML Source Code

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block title%}video_detail.html{%endblock%}

{%load staticfiles%}
{%block extrastyle%}{%static 'photo/photo.css'%}{%endblock%}

{%block content%}

<div id='content'>

        <h2>{{object.title}}</h2>

        <table class="photo-detail">
        <tr>
        <td>
                <video width="960" height="540" preload="none" controls>
                        <source src="{{object.video.url}}" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2""/>
                        <source src="{{object.video.url}}" type="video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis""/>
                        <source src="{{object.video.url}}" type="video/oggi; codecs="theora, vorbis""/>
                        Your browser does not support the video element.
                </video>
        </td>

        <td>
        <ul>
                <li>Video Description</li>
                {%if object.description%}<p>    {{object.description|linebreaks}}</p>
                {%else%}<p>(blank)</p>{%endif%}
                <li>Upload Date</li>
                <p>{{object.upload_date}}</p>
                <li>Album Name</li>
                <p><a href="{%url 'video:album_detail' object.album.id%}">    {{object.album.name}}</a></p>
                <li>Download</li>
                <p><a href="{{object.video.url}}" download>{{object.title}}    </a></p>
        </ul>
        </td>
        </tr></table>

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It will be really hard to help without looking at the code. Please update your question to include all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the html5-Video-Tag you've set this parameter in the Video-TAG: `preload="none"`

Comment: Are you saying that I should insert preload="none" to video tag?

Comment: Two Parameters are interesting: autobuffer and preload, If you set autobuffer, it will not start, until enough data is loaded to play. Have you files for .mp4 and .ogg too? its important  otherwise it will start every video to test the playability.

Comment: @KigaelLee Please consider adding a comment if someone has helped you with a question.  And take advantage of the comment  'upvote' and Answer upvote and Accepted with a checkmark when it is the best of Answers and helps you.  Many of your questions have no feedback of any kind.  Feedback helps you and the provider of the tips toward continuing their support efforts.